# Mac OS X Safari 6 default search engine change between possible values

Tags: cocoa, safari, osx-mountain-lion, safari6

I would like to change the Safari default search engine programmatically on Mac OS X. I know there are 3 possible values, but where Safari stores the current value? I would like to change from Google to Yahoo from Cocoa code. Is it possible?

I've seen in the a `SearchProviderIdentifierMigratedToSystemPreference` variable is set to YES in the `com.apple.Safari.plist` file, that can be located at `~/Library/Preferences`. This could be the key to the current value, but where the "System Preference" is stored? Do you have any clues about this?

---

Update: I've found the this command `defaults read -g NSPreferredWebServices` always returns the selected default search engine. The problem with this is that when I change the value of it, the safari doesn't changes the value.
Here's the command that changes the value to Bing:
`defaults write -g NSPreferredWebServices '{NSWebServicesProviderWebSearch = { NSDefaultDisplayName = Bing; NSProviderIdentifier = "com.bing.www"; }; }';`

This command should be executed in the terminal.

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't and since then I had other tasks to do. I left the question here, because I am still interested.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (tested with macOS 11.5), the `NSPreferredWebServices` sets the System search engine (where Spotlight redirects you when launching a web search with Spotlight for instance).
This key is updated whenever Safari’s search engine is updated.

Another key is updated too when Safari’s search engine changes: `SearchProviderShortName` (in domain `com.apple.Safari`). And apparently this is the one to update to change Safari’s search engine. (Set to `DuckDuckGo` to use DuckDuckGo for instance.)

Previously (before `SearchProviderIdentifierMigratedToSystemPreference`), the key was `SearchProviderIdentifier`, and the value was `com.duckduckgo` for the DuckDuckGo search engine.

My recommendation would be to set all of them to be safe:

```sh
defaults write -g NSPreferredWebServices '{NSWebServicesProviderWebSearch = { NSDefaultDisplayName = Bing; NSProviderIdentifier = "com.bing.www"; }; }'
defaults write com.apple.Safari SearchProviderIdentifier -string com.bing.www
defaults write com.apple.Safari SearchProviderShortName -string Bing
```

---

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224386